# Modify IPublishedContent properties in Umbraco custom controller

Tags: c#, umbraco

First of all, I realise that the core of my problmen probably is the way that I'm trying to solve it, so let me first explain what I'm trying to do.

I have a Layout where I output a property.

Layout.cshtml

```
inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
...
//More of the layout here

<title>@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("title")</title>

...
```

This is the base of the other templates:

FullWidth.cshtml

```
@{ Layout = "Layout.cshtml"; }
... layout here
```

This all works well, I make sure every document type has a property called `title` and it gets printed all the time.

Now I'm creating a page, where some data from a database is being displayed. So I created a custom controller:

```
public class ProductController : RenderMvcController
{
    public ActionResult Index(Rendermodel model, int id)
    {
          var viewModel = new CustomRenderModel(model.Content);
          viewModel.Product = Database.GetProductById(id);
          return CurrentTemplate(viewModel);
    }

}
```

This works great too, but the next thing I want to do is also set the title based on whatever is retrieved from the database. Something like this:

```
var viewModel = new CustomRenderModel(model.Content);
var product = Database.GetProductById(id);
viewModel.Product = product;
viewModel.Content.SetPropertyValue("title", product.name");
```

Obviously this doesnt work because the IPublishedContent is readonly. I'm just wondering what the best way is to modify a property like that.

I realise that exposing a `SetPropertyValue` is a bad idea probably, but what would be the way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would render this title in a separate partial view and give that partial view a specific model to render.

Have a look at this blog post I wrote which shows you how to do that.
http://www.codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-to-optimise-your-website-for-search-engines-seo-in-umbraco/

Kind regards

Paul

Comment: Thanks :) Yeah I probably figured I'd have to go this route. How would you pass the data from the rendermvc controller to the partial?

Comment: In the ActionResult on the last line it says:

`return PartialView(PartialViewPath("_MetaData"), model);`

Then in the partial view you use that model like this:

`@model NamespaceName.ModelName`

or 

`@inherits UmbracoViewPage<NamespaceName.ModelName>`

Comment: Partial View Path is just a short method i created so i could use folders for partial view files. It basically returns a path for the partial view.

`private string PartialViewPath(string name)
        {
            return $"~/Views/Partials/SiteLayout/{name}.cshtml";
        }`

Answer (score 1):

I know, this is an old post, but other people might search for a solution to this question. It absolutely makes sense to be able to overwrite property values, especially in route hijacking scenarios. The solution is to write an own implementation of IPublishedContent. It only needs a few lines of code. The solution is shown in this blog post:
https://www.formfakten.de/themen/2018/08/publishedcontent-with-overridden-properties

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes